# Calculate AVERAGE if condition is met in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, pivot-table

I would like to know the quickest way to sum all the values in column O if they have the same label in column D, and take the average of these values.

My worksheet is enormous and the number of the same label for each class is also different.

How can I do this faster than doing this manually for each label in column D?

Comment: Have you considered using something like `Sumifs()`/`Countifs()` or a PivotTable?

Comment: Look into the [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) and [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)  functions.

Comment: Voting to migrate this to [SuperUser - Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) as it appears to be about rudimentary worksheet function implementation.

Comment: @pnuts - With the recent changes to the `Excel` tag wiki that expressly acknowledge *complex formula development* while discouraging *general help ... for single worksheet functions*,  it seems hypocritical to post an answer involving a single function. This is not a bad question; merely one in the wrong SE site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79263/discussion-between-jeeped-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 2):

Please try a [PivotTable](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) with ColumnD for ROWS and Average of O for VALUES:

[image: SO30560025 example]